# flex scrolling issue - hopefully simple problem

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, rendering

Hi I am having an issue with scrolling in flex. I am using a large canvas with a number of label objects. A lot of the labels are off-screen until the user scrolls down or up, this is unavoidable due to the amount of information that has to be displayed so I have considered alternatives to this in case anyone is thinking of any. What is happening though is that the canvas seems to clip its labels when I scroll away from the respective areas on the canvas.

E.g. As I run the app all the content is visible perfectly at the top of the container, then as I scroll down the canvas and scroll back to the top, the content has disappeared. I am genuinely stumped on this so I would appreciate if anyone could explain why this is happening or if there is a way around it. I would imagine that Flex is trying to do something sophisticated like recycle pixels and render in real time or something like that, but I really don't need that. The app is simply just a display so it is not interactive and will simply only contain labels and a few sliders to represent data.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Conor

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible version of this issue? Flex does reuse the item-renderer objects, but that shouldn't cause any issues. If there are 100 items in total and only 10 are visible at a given time, flex will create only 11 item renderer objects and reuse those upon scrolling.

Comment: @Amargosh I'm not sure what you mean by minimal reproducible version. My flex app is essentially just this- a tile list and a big canvas (1260 * 800 | w * h). When the user selects something from the tilelist the canvas' visibility is set to true, and inside this canvas I have 219 components in total. This screens needs to be a scrolling canvas, purely because it is effectively a massive aggregated report page. A lot of the components are placed in close proximity to one another also if that is of any significance. If I could disable redrawing or anything it would be helpful I'd imagine.

Comment: post your code and we might be able to better help.

Answer (score 0):

(putting this as an Answer rather than a Comment so I can put in the link)

Ive seen dissappearing images on a TileList and found a solution [here](http://blog.152.org/2009/11/flex-tilelist-cell-switching-problem.html). It might be that you are using the embedded images, or a copy of an image for the canvas display objects? I know that the tileList uses a pool of item renderers and thats why it was problematic, but that is not the case for a Canvas,.